# XSLT to filter out nodes and generate new xml

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I have the below XML where I need to filter out `<rule>` node which has a child node of `<match>` with attribute value not containing `.aspx`.

The original XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="welcome2020" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="welcome2020"/>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.mywebsite.org/Pages/.welcome2020aspx" appendQueryString="false"/>
        </rule>
        <rule name="Page to Page Redirect">
            <match url="/Staff/Pages/Ashley.aspx"/>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="services/Staff/Pages/Ashley.aspx"/>
        </rule>
        <rule name="Page to Page Redirect">
            <match url="ENT"/>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="services/audiology/earnosethroat.aspx"/>
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

After transformation, I want the XML to be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="welcome2020" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="welcome2020"/>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.mywebsite.org/Pages/.welcome2020aspx" appendQueryString="false"/>
        </rule> 
        <rule name="Page to Page Redirect">
            <match url="ENT"/>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="services/audiology/earnosethroat.aspx"/>
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Some XSLT that I have come up with is below. I am basically unable to come up with a template that is able to select parent based on matched child node. Is that even possible?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//rewrite/rules/rule/match[contains(@url,'aspx')]/parent::rule" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The idea is that the XSLT basically removes any `<rule>` node that has a child node `<match>` and the `<match>` node has an URL attribute that contains `.aspx`

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service:https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The idea is that the XSLT basically removes any `<rule>` node that has a child node `<match>` and the `<match>` node has an URL attribute that contains `.aspx`

So how about:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="rule[contains(match/@url,'.aspx')]" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you!! what's the difference between what you have vs this `<xsl:template  match="rule[match[contains(@url,'aspx')]]"/>`  ? is it testing the 'contains' test on the child vs parent node?

Comment: @AJSwift It's the same thing in different style.